# 1.9 - Add product to category collection by ID

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category, category-products

I want to add a product to a category page depending on the **category ID**.  This product is not part of the category.

In `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` I see the following line:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
```

Would it be possible to have an `if` underneath? - Is this the right place?

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
if ($this->getCategoryId() == 123) {
  //add product id 456 to the collection
}
```

If so, how do I add a product to the `$category` collection?

And further to this, is it possible to insert it in a particular place, lets say inbetween the 3rd and 4th product?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code fastest way to set product to category

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
if ($this->getCategoryId() == 123) {
  //add product id 456 to the collection
    $productIds[$product->getId()]  = 1; // here key is product id and value is position 
    $category->setPostedProducts($productIds);
    $category->save();
}
```